# MySQL LEFT Join and SUM items from second table

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, timestamp

Is there any way to JOIN two tables in MySQL and SUM the elements in the second table for every distinct *timestamp* that is in the table?

So here is my table structure:

[image: MySQL Workbench Structure]

And here is some example Data:

devices table:

```
id  userId  time            mac           upload download deltaUpload deltaDownload
1   1   2008-01-01 00:00:01 00:00:00:00:01  0       0         100     1000
2   1   2008-01-01 00:00:01 00:00:00:00:02  0       0         400     4000
3   1   2008-01-01 00:00:01 00:00:00:00:03  0       0         0       500
4   2   2008-01-01 00:00:01 10:00:00:00:00  0       0         1000    5000
5   2   2008-01-01 00:00:01 20:00:00:00:00  0       0         4000    5000
6   1   2008-01-01 00:10:01 00:00:00:00:01  100     1000      500     10000
7   1   2008-01-01 00:10:01 00:00:00:00:02  400     4000      10000   500
8   1   2008-01-01 00:10:01 00:00:00:00:03  0       500       5000    5000
9   2   2008-01-01 00:10:01 10:00:00:00:00  1000    5000      500     10000
10  2   2008-01-01 00:10:01 20:00:00:00:00  4000    5000      10000   20000
```

users table:

```
id  username
1   SomeUsername
2   SomeOtherUser
```

And basically what I want to know is a rowset which has an entry for every timestamp (every 10min in this case), with the sum of the (delta)traffic of all MAC-addresses for a user.

Example Result for this table and user with userid = 1

```
username         time                  upload  download
SomeUsername    2008-01-01 00:00:01     500     5500
SomeUsername    2008-01-01 00:10:01     15500   15500
```

This is how far I've come with this query

```
SELECT 
    `users`.`username` AS 'username',
    `devices`.`time` AS 'time',
    `devices`.`deltaUpload` AS 'upload',
    `devices`.`deltaDownload` AS 'download'
FROM
    `devices`
        LEFT JOIN
    `users` ON (`users`.`id` = `devices`.`userId`)
GROUP BY`devices`.`time`;
```

And I seem to only get garbage/no results

Comment: are all devices.userId available in the users table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks good but you are not using `SUM`.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    `users`.`username` AS 'username',
    `devices`.`time` AS 'time',
    SUM(`devices`.`deltaUpload`) AS 'upload',
    SUM(`devices`.`deltaDownload`) AS 'download'
FROM
 `devices`
    LEFT JOIN
 `users` ON (`users`.`id` = `devices`.`userId`)
GROUP BY `users`.`username`, `devices`.`time`;
```

Comment: thank you.. well I guess it got too late for solving this myself. kinda feel stupid now..